# wrong number of template arguments(1, should be 2). Can anyone take a look?

Tags: dictionary, templates, inheritance, binary-search-tree, treenode

I'm creating a dictionary using BST as derive class from the dictionary class. since I'm using template, I encounter one error of which I figure out the reason but can't solve it. can anyone figure out? Thanks

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;


template <class K, class E> class BST;
template <class K, class E>
struct pair{K first; E second;};

template <class K, class E>
class TreeNode {
friend class BST <K, E>;

public:
    K data;
    TreeNode<pair<K, E>> *leftChild;
    TreeNode<pair<K, E>> *rightChild;
};

template <class K, class E>
class Dictionary {
public:
    virtual bool IsEmpty() const = 0;  // return true if dictionary is empty
    virtual pair<K, E>* Get(const K&) const = 0;
    // return pointer to the pair w. specified key
   virtual void Insert(const pair <K, E>& k) = 0;
   // insert the given pair; if key ia a duplicate, update associate element
   virtual void Delete(const K& k) = 0;  // delete pair w. specified key
};

template <class K, class E>
class BST:public Dictionary<K,E> {
public:
    BST();
    pair<K, E>* Get(const K& k)const;
    pair<K, E>* RankGet(int r);
    pair<K, E>* Get(TreeNode <pair <K, E>>* p, const K& k)const;
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    void Insert(const pair<K, E >& thePair);
    void Delete(const K& k);

private:
    TreeNode <pair<K, E>> *root;


};

template<class K, class E>
BST<K,E>::BST(){root = nullptr;}
template <class K, class E>
pair<K, E>* BST<K, E> :: Get(const K& k) const
{// Driver
    return Get(root, k);
}

template <class K, class E>
bool BST<K,E>::IsEmpty() const
{
    return root==nullptr;
}

template <class K, class E>
pair<K, E>* BST<K, E>::Get(TreeNode <pair <K, E>>* p, const K& k)const
{// Workhorse
   if (!p) return 0; //empty
   if (k < p->data.first) return Get(p->leftChild, k);
   if (k > p->data.first) return Get(p->rightChild, k);
   return &p->data;
}

template <class K, class E>
pair<K, E>* BST<K, E>::RankGet(int r) //search by rank
{ //search the BST for the rth smallest pair
   TreeNode < pair<K, E>> * currentNode = root;
   while (currentNode) {
       if (r < currentNode -> leftSize)
          currentNode = currentNode -> leftChild;
       else if (r > currentNode -> leftSize)
       {
          r -= currentNode -> leftSize;
          currentNode = currentNode -> rightChild;
       }
       else return & currentNode -> data;
   }
   return 0;
}

template <class K, class E>
void BST<K, E > :: Insert(const pair<K, E >& thePair)
{  // insert thePair into the BST
   // search for thePair.first，pp parent of p
   TreeNode < pair<K, E>> *p = root, *pp = 0;
   while (p) {
      pp = p;
      if (thePair.first < p->data.first) p = p->leftChild;
      else if(thePair.first > p->data.first)p = p->rightChild;
      else // duplicate, update associated element
          { p->data.second = thePair.second; return;}
   }
 // perform insertion
 p = new TreeNode< pair<K, E>> (thePair);
if (root) // tree is nonempty
   if (thePair.first < pp->data.first) pp->leftChild = p;
   else pp->rightChild = p;
   else root = p;
}


int main()
{
    BST<int, char> bst;
    pair<int,char> p;

    int A[11]= {50,3,30,40,80,35,2,20,15,60,70};
    char B[11]= {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
    cout<<A[i]<<" "<<B[i]<<endl;
   //maxHeap.Push(A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the TreeNode should have 2 template argument I have tried to give it "K" as second beside pair<K, E> but it does not work

Comment: Why are `K` and `E` classes and not typenames? Why are some classes tempated with `std::pair<K, E>` instead of `typename K, typename E`?

Comment: I thought they were interchangeable. Pair is the struct as you can see that will have two members "element and key". the goal is to have a node with the pair key and element, hence tempated with pair<K, E>

Comment: You can't use them interchangably, either `K, E` or `pair<K, E>`. Are you aware that there is actually an `std::tuple` in `utility` and you are also `using namespace std` which might lead to problems in combination with your own `pair` class!